# How to tell if a Linux system is big endian or little endian?

Tags: central-processing-unit

I know that certain processors are Big Endian and others are Little Endian. But is there a command, bash script, python script or series of commands that can be used at the command line to determine if a system is Big Endian or Little Endian? Something like:

```
if <some code> then
    echo Big Endian
else
    echo Little Endian
fi
```

Or is it more simple to just determine what processor the system is using and go with that to determine its Endianess?

Comment: Here's the solution using perl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610849/finding-if-the-system-is-little-endian-or-big-endian-with-perl

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88934/is-there-a-system-command-in-linux-that-reports-the-endianness | https://askubuntu.com/questions/902907/check-system-is-little-endian-or-big-endian | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859098/testing-endianness-of-system-with-the-unix-shell

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has already plenty of answers on U/L, ServerFault and even AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

On a Big Endian-System (Solaris on SPARC)

```
$ echo -n I | od -to2 | head -n1 | cut -f2 -d" " | cut -c6
```

0

On a little endian system (Linux on x86)

```
$ echo -n I | od -to2 | head -n1 | cut -f2 -d" " | cut -c6
```

1

---

The solution above is clever and works great for Linux *86 and Solaris Sparc.

I needed a shell-only (no Perl) solution that also worked on AIX/Power and HPUX/Itanium.  Unfortunately the last two don't play nice: AIX reports "6" and HPUX gives an empty line.

Using your solution, I was able to craft something that worked on all these Unix systems:

`$ echo I | tr -d [:space:] | od -to2 | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c6`

Regarding the Python solution someone posted, it does not work in Jython because the JVM treats everything as Big.  If anyone can get it to work in Jython, please post!

Also, I found this, which explains the endianness of various platforms.  Some hardware can operate in either mode depending on what the O/S selects:  http://labs.hoffmanlabs.com/node/544

---

If you're going to use awk this line can be simplified to:

```
echo -n I | od -to2 | awk '{ print substr($2,6,1); exit}'
```

For small Linux boxes that don't have 'od' (say OpenWrt) then try 'hexdump':

```
echo -n I | hexdump -o | awk '{ print substr($2,6,1); exit}'
```

Comment: That's an upper-case `I` (eye) rather than a lower-case `l` (ell) by the way.

Comment: (Solaris) -> (Solaris, Sparc), although Sparc >= V9 is bi endian.

Comment: Care to explain how it works?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Android (Nexus 5). Not sure why...

Comment: `printf "\x1" | od -to2 | awk 'NR==1{print$2==1}'`

Answer (score 71):

If you are on a fairly recent Linux machine **(most anything after 2012)** then `lscpu` now contains this information:

```
$ lscpu | grep Endian
Byte Order:            Little Endian
```

This was added to `lscpu` in version 2.19, which is found in Fedora >= 17, CentOS >= 6.0, Ubuntu >= 12.04.

Note that I found this answer from [this terrific answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88934/is-there-a-system-command-in-linux-that-reports-the-endianness). That answer has a lot of relevant information, this post is just a summary of it.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a more elegant python one-line script

```
python -c "import sys;sys.exit(0 if sys.byteorder=='big' else 1)"
```

exit code `0` means big endian and `1` means little endian

or just change `sys.exit` to `print` for a printable output

Comment: This won't work on RHEL 5.x/CentOS 5.x systems which are running Python 2.4.x.  Here's a fix: `python -c "import sys;sys.exit(int(sys.byteorder!='big'))"`

Answer (score 16):

You can take advantage of ELF file format to determine the endianness of your system. For example, print the first six bytes of an arbitrary ELF file in hex:

```
xxd -c 1 -l 6 /bin/ls

0000000: 7f  .
0000001: 45  E
0000002: 4c  L
0000003: 46  F
0000004: 02  .
0000005: 01  .
```

If the last line (the sixth byte) is 01, according to [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), 01 is little endian and 02 is big endian.

If you haven't got an `xxd` on your box (and do have busybox), try this:

```
hexdump -s 5 -n 1 -C /bin/busybox
```

Comment: I think you mean of an arbitrary ELF ... Since there are other executable types including shell scripts, perl, python, etc. Not saying you're wrong otherwise though - just saying that it's worth remembering that there are other executable types (and for interest the code is in the text segment hence the old text file busy error).

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected it!

Comment: @TongZhou Welcome; glad to be of help!

Comment: Awesome! First method to work for busybox-based embedded OSes.

Comment: The hexdump version is awesome. It works well on busybox systems.

Comment: `hexdump` isn't posix either. `od -j5 -N1 -An -td1 some-ELF-file` should work on every posix system.

Answer (score 10):

The main answer can be simplified slightly using `awk`:

On a Big Endian system (Solaris, SPARC)

```
$ echo -n I | od -to2 | awk 'FNR==1{ print substr($2,6,1)}'
0
```

On a Little Endian system (Linux, Intel)

```
$ echo -n I | od -to2 | awk 'FNR==1{ print substr($2,6,1)}'
1
```

#### Newer Linux Kernels

As of version 2.19 of the util-linux package the command `lscpu` started including a field related to Endianness. So now you can simply use this command to find this out:

```
$ lscpu | grep -i byte
Byte Order:            Little Endian
```

This has been confirmed on Ubuntu 12.10 and CentOS 6. So I would be willing to assume that most 3.0+ Linux Kernels are now offering this.

On Debian/Ubuntu systems you can also use this command, not sure of when it became available:

```
$ dpkg-architecture | grep -i end
DEB_BUILD_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
DEB_HOST_ARCH_ENDIAN=little
```

#### References

- [Is there a system command, in Linux, that reports the endianness?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88934/7453)

Answer (score 9):

This Python script should work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from struct import pack
if pack('@h', 1) == pack('<h', 1):
    print "Little Endian"
else:
    print "Big Endian"
```

Comment: One liner: `python -c "from struct import pack;import sys;sys.exit(int(pack('@h',1)==pack('<h',1)))"`. The exit code is 0 for big endian and 1 for little endian.

Answer (score 9):

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.byteorder)"
```

It would print the endianess of the system.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it in Jython.  Since Jython (Python on the JVM) runs on a VM, it always reports big endian, regardless of the hardware.

This solution works for Linux, Solaris, AIX, and HPUX.  Have not tested on Windows:

```
    from java.lang import System
    for property, value in dict(System.getProperties()).items():
        if property.endswith('cpu.endian'):
            return value
```

Answer (score 2):

A single-line command based on ELF format:
`hexdump -s 5 -n 1 /bin/sh`

Comment: Edit: -n 1, sorry ;)

Comment: This is the exact same method as a [previous answer](http://serverfault.com/a/749469/214507), which also provided more details than yours.

Answer (score 2):

I dislike a bit the answer that relies on the ELF format, as it is not used everywhere (it could be scripts, or another binfmt, or even a cygwin system). Here is a relatively portable which relies only on POSIX and `hexdump` (so busybox-compatible, if aiming for POSIX compatibility, `awk` should be used instead):

```bash
if test `printf '\0\1' | hexdump -e '/2 "%04x"'` -eq 0100
then
    echo little
else
    echo big
fi
```

Also test for middle-endian:

```bash
case `printf '\0\1\2\3' | hexdump -e '/4 "%08x"'` in
03020100) echo little;;
00010203) echo big;;
01000302) echo mid-big;;
02030001) echo mid-little;; # these two might be swapped, adjust accordingly
*) echo unknown endianness
esac
```

---

How is this working?

1. Printf prints byte-by-byte, in order, 4 bytes (chars) whose hexadecimal values are: `00 01 02 03`.
2. That output buffer is piped to `hexdump`
3. `-e` specifies a format string for hexdump to display data:

   - The `/4` instructs it to apply formatting to groups of 4 bytes at once (from the man: *The byte count is an optional positive integer. If specified it defines the number of bytes to be interpreted by each iteration of the format*). That group will be read in `hexdump`'s native endianess.
   - The `"%08x"` is the output format (8 hexadecimal chars with a leading 0).

The idea here is that `hexdump` is compiled for the platform it's running on, and will read the number in its native endianess, then display it in a "human-readable" big-endian format. X -> Y endian is the same swap as Y -> X (so swapping twice returns the input data).

Hexdump does the native -> big conversion for us, which we exploit here to perform a big -> native swap by specifying the word size. The use of `hexdump` was inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465138).

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different requirement: I need a test like this in a program build configure script to determine whether the **compile target machine** is bit or little endian, **without executing code**. The script must deposit `#define HAVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN 1` into a `config.h` header, or else `#define HAVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN 0`.

The compile target machine may be different from the build machine, since we may be cross-compiling, which also explains why the test mustn't try to run any compiled code. It is out of the question to have a little C program with a `printf` statement that spits out the answer.

A possible solution is this. We generate a file called `conftest.c` which contains this:

```
#define USPELL(C0, C1, C2, C3) \                                             
  ((unsigned) C0 << 24 | \                                              
   (unsigned) C1 << 16 | \                                              
   (unsigned) C2 << 8 | (unsigned) C3)                                       

unsigned x[6] = {                                                       
  0,                                                                         
  USPELL('L', 'I', 'S', 'P'),                                                
  USPELL('U', 'N', 'I', 'X'),                                                
  USPELL('C', 'O', 'R', 'E'),                                                
  USPELL('D', 'W', 'I', 'M'),                                                
  0                                                                          
};
```

Now, we compile this to `conftest.o` using:

```
$ /path/to/cross-compiling/cc conftest.c -c
```

Then we run:

```
$ strings conftest.o
PSILXINUEROCMIWD
```

If the string `PSILXINUEROCMIWD` occurs, the target is little-endian. If the string `LISPUNIXCOREDWIM` occurs, it is big-endian. If neither string occurs or, even more astonishingly, both do, then the test has failed.

This approach works because the "fourcc" constants calculated in the program have machine-independent values, denoting the same integers regardless of endianness.  Their storage representation in the object file follows the endianness of the target system, and that is visible via the character-based view under `strings`.

The two zero guard words ensure that the string is isolated. That isn't strictly necessary, but it ensures that the string we are looking for is not embedded in some other string, meaning that `strings` will output it on a line by itself.

P.S. the `USPELL` macro doesn't parenthesize the argument insertions because it's crafted for this specific purpose, not for re-use.

Comment: Not that it is necessary for all projects but does autoconf/automake not have this check? My projects are always small enough where I can make my own Makefiles (though not always basic) so I don't really know those tools other than making some modifications when necessary and the general interface..but I do wonder if they have detection. Perhaps you didn't need it even if it does, just thought I'd throw the possibility out.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution that involves thoroughly mis-using posix shell exit codes :

```
gawk/mawk/mawk2/nawk 'BEGIN { # system() returns 1 
                              # if little-endian.
                              # to check BE, change that -c 2 to -c 5
     print system("
          exit \140<<<\47\47 gnu-od | grep -c 2\140") }'
```

> \47 = ascii single quote, and \140 is ascii grave accent
>
> - except gnu-**gawk -S** sandbox mode, which disables **system( )**

what that does is execute this —>

> exit ` <<<'' god | grep -c 2 `

inside a posix sh shell, basically asking gnu-od to show you a default 2-byte octals of a single `\n (d=10)` character.

on little-endian systems, it shows as **000012**. But on big-endian systems, the extra padding byte causes gnu-od to upshift the octals. decimal of 10*256=2560=5x8x8x8, so the resulting 2-byte octal is **005000**. Then use grep counter feature to locate either the 2 or the 5.

exit codes are supposed to be that 0 means success and every number larger means some sort of error. but since grep counter already helped us inverted that, the returned "exit code" of the system command is already in the awk boolean sense of true(1) and false(0).

Answer (score 0):

On fairly modern Linux (6.2.16) x86_64:

```
$ time lscpu | grep 'Byte Order'
Byte Order:                      Little Endian

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.007s


$ time echo '#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#warning LE
#else
#warning BE
#endif'| gcc -march=native -E - 2>&1 | sed -nr '/^.*[[:space:]]((B|L)E)[[:space:]].*$/{s/^.*[[:space:]]((B|L)E)[[:space:]].*$/\1/g;p;}'

LE

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.013s
```

Since on some machines, endianness can depend on compiler options,
and on setarch(1) / personality(2) settings, and the execution times
are very similar,  between above commands,  I'd use gcc >= v12 with
above options to get native bit order for current personality(2) ,
if you have a C compiler installed -- this also permits use of different
-march=/-mtune/-mcpu settings to "lookup" Endianness of other CPU variants
/ architectures.